# wsdl error: XML error parsing WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I try to send information from client side to web service. But it shows me this error..

> Error encontrado:wsdl error: XML error parsing WSDL from http://cfd.sicofi.com.mx/SicofiWS/CFD.asmx?wsdl on line 5: EntityRef: expecting ';'

and my php code

```
$serverURL = 'http://cfd.sicofi.com.mx/SicofiWS';
$serverScript = 'CFD.asmx';
$metodoALlamar = 'GeneraCFD';

$cliente = new nusoap_client("$serverURL/$serverScript?wsdl",'wsdl');
```